# Charles failed to get https requests

Tags: https, charles-proxy

I have installed Charles Root Certificate on my iOS device and my MacBook. However, when i use iPhone proxing by Charles, Charles fails to get HTTPS requests. It shows that
[`SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBpUd.png)

My Charles version is 4.0.2 and I have installed certificate on my mac and trusted.
My iOS version is 10.3.1 and I have also installed certificate on iphone.

Can anyone help my on this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iOS 10.3+ introduced a new setting to grant permission for certificates.  Since you have the Charles certificate installed, then all you need to do is go to Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings > Toggle the cert to on.  Hope this helps you.

Comment: i've fixed this problem yesterday.But your answer is right. Thanks a lot.